# TypeError: must be str, not bytes при сложении строк. Как написать правильный синтаксис?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import hashlib
data = 'fdffffffffff'
sign = hashlib.md5("app_id=75545459127method=users.getInfosecure=1session_key="+data+"7a055eddee3e620b06d26d95e2gfgfgffga7414jjhjh271df".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
print(str(sign))
```

ОШИБКА
TypeError: must be str, not bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас сначала для строки после `7a055eddee3e620b06d26d95e2gfgfgffga7414jjhjh271df` вызывается метод `encode`, который превращает её в `bytes`, а потом выполняется конкатенация с `data` и остальной частью строки. Или пометьте все строки как байтовые

```
data = b'fdffffffffff'
hashlib.md5(b'app_id=75545459127method=users.getInfosecure=1session_key=' + data + b'7a055eddee3e620b06d26d95e2gfgfgffga7414jjhjh271dfb')
```

или оберните операцию конкатенации в дополнительные скобки, чтобы явно задать порядок выполнения операций

```
hashlib.md5(("app_id=75545459127method=users.getInfosecure=1session_key=" + data + "7a055eddee3e620b06d26d95e2gfgfgffga7414jjhjh271df").encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: в дополнительные скобки, +

Comment: @СергейВикторович для читаемости, стоит *перед* каждым плюсом новую строку добавить.

Comment: а как сделать конкатенации двух хэшей md5?